# Importar datos de excel a Sql Server con Asp.Net Core MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Que tal estoy trabajando en un proyecto en el cual se requiere que los datos de un ahoja de excel sean almacenados en SqlServer, hastá el momento tengo lo siguiente, Controlador:

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("Import")]
        public string Import([Bind]Archivos files)
        {
            string sWebRootFolder = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            string sFileName = files.Files.ToString();
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(sWebRootFolder, sFileName));
            try
            {
                using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(file))
                {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                    int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
                    int ColCount = worksheet.Dimension.Columns;
                    bool bHeaderRow = true;
                    for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++)
                    {
                        for (int col = 1; col <= ColCount; col++)
                        {
                            if (bHeaderRow)
                            {
                                sb.Append(worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString() + "\t");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sb.Append(worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString() + "\t");
                            }
                        }
                        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                    return sb.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "Some error occured while importing." + ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Modelo :

```
public class Archivos
    {
        [Display(Name = "Files2")]
        public IFormFile[] Files { get; set; }
    }
```

Vista:

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="Files2" name="Files2" />
    <button type="submit" asp-controller="ImportExport" asp-action="Import">OK</button>

    <br />
    <br />
    <table id="exceltable"></table>
```

aún no logro obtener el arcihvo seleccionado, podrían compartir algún ejemplo o link para revisar y comparar mi código? de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en tu pagina aspx agrega el hmtl tu name es files, a tu metodo agregale que es tipo post, enlugar de get

Answer (score 0):

Dejo el código ya funcional por si es de ayuda poara alguien, consulte varios sitios para generar esta función.

Controlador:

```
public IActionResult ImportFile([Bind] Archivos fl)
    {
        if (fl.Document != null)
        {

            ClassBase ccl = new ClassBase();
            IFormFile[] file;
            file = fl.Document;
            string folderName = "Upload";


            var path_Root = "//ruta_demi_server/carpeta/Archivos";
            var path2 = path_Root + "/" + folderName;
            var pathfile = "";

            if (!Directory.Exists(path2))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path2);

            var y = file.Count();
            string[] data = new string[y];

            for (int x = 0; x < file.Length; x++)
            {
                path2 = path2 +"/"+ file[x].FileName;

                var stream = new FileStream(path2, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

                file[x].CopyTo(stream);
                data[x] = path2;

                stream.Close();
            }
            ccl.InsertExceldataOk(path2);

        }
      return View();
    }

}
```

Modelo (claseBase):

```
 public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration;
        public void InsertExceldataOk(string fullPath)
        {

           var hasHeader = true;

           using (var con = new SqlConnection(conectionexcel))
            {
                con.Open();
                FileInfo excelFile = new FileInfo(fullPath);

                using (var epPackage = new ExcelPackage(excelFile))
                {
                    var pck = epPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.First();

                    var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
                    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
                    foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1,
                    ws.Dimension.End.Column])
                    {
                        tbl.Columns.Add(hasHeader ? firstRowCell.Text :
                        string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));
                    }
                    var startRow = hasHeader ? 2 : 1;
                    for (int rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
                    {
                        var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];
                        DataRow row = tbl.Rows.Add();
                        foreach (var cell in wsRow)
                        {
                            row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
                        }
                    }

                using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(conectionexcel))
                {
                      //Al cargar el archivo solo se eliminan los datos con cierto ID
                 string query = "delete from Despachos where Despacho = '039998'";

                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con2);
                        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                        con2.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con2.Close();



                    }


                    using (var sqlCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conectionexcel))
                        {

                           sqlCopy.DestinationTableName = "[Despachos]";
                           sqlCopy.WriteToServer(tbl);

                        }

                }
            }


        }
```